# Understanding a malloc_history dump

Tags: objective-c, ios, malloc-history

If you have ever asked how can I debug releasing/alloc issues in objective-c, you will have came across these environment settings that can help track the problem down:

- `NSZombieEnabled` - Keeps abjects around after release, so you can get pointers etc.
- `MallocStackLogging` - keeps object history for reference later
- `NSDebugEnabled`

You set all of these to `YES` in the 'environment' section of the 'arguments' tab in the 'executables' (found in group tree) info.

---

So, Im getting this console output

> MyApp [**4413**:40b] -[CALayer
>   retainCount]: message sent to
>   deallocated instance **0x4dbb170**

then open terminal, while the debugger has forwarded the break and type:

> malloc_history **4413 0x4dbb170**

Then, I get a big text dump, and as far as I understand the important bit is this:

1

```
ALLOC 0x4dbb160-0x4dbb171 [size=18]:
thread_a0375540 |start | main |
UIApplicationMain | GSEventRun |
GSEventRunModal | CFRunLoopRunInMode |
CFRunLoopRunSpecific | __CFRunLoopRun
| __CFRunLoopDoTimer |
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
| __NSFireDelayedPerform |
-[todoListViewController drillDocumentMenu:] |
-[documentListViewController drillIntoDocumentWithToDoRecord:] |
-[documentViewController OpenTodoDocument:OfType:WithPath:] |
-[documentViewController OpenDocumentOfType:WithPath:] |
-[documentViewController managePDFDocumentWithPath:] |
-[PDFDocument loadPDFDocumentWithPath:andTitle:] |
-[PDFDocument getMetaData] | CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction |
ListDictionaryObjects(char const*,
CGPDFObject*, void*) | NSLog | NSLogv
| _CFLogvEx | __CFLogCString |
asl_send | _asl_send_level_message |
asl_set_query | strdup | malloc |
malloc_zone_malloc
```

2

```
FREE  0x4dbb160-0x4dbb171 [size=18]:
thread_a0375540 |start | main |
UIApplicationMain | GSEventRun |
GSEventRunModal | CFRunLoopRunInMode |
CFRunLoopRunSpecific | __CFRunLoopRun
| __CFRunLoopDoTimer |
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
| __NSFireDelayedPerform |
-[todoListViewController drillDocumentMenu:] |
-[documentListViewController drillIntoDocumentWithToDoRecord:] |
-[documentViewController OpenTodoDocument:OfType:WithPath:] |
-[documentViewController OpenDocumentOfType:WithPath:] |
-[documentViewController managePDFDocumentWithPath:] |
-[PDFDocument loadPDFDocumentWithPath:andTitle:] |
-[PDFDocument getMetaData] | CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction |
ListDictionaryObjects(char const*,
CGPDFObject*, void*) | NSLog | NSLogv
| _CFLogvEx | __CFLogCString |
asl_send | _asl_send_level_message |
asl_free | free
```

3

```
ALLOC 0x4dbb170-0x4dbb19f [size=48]:
thread_a0375540 |start | main |
UIApplicationMain | GSEventRun |
GSEventRunModal | CFRunLoopRunInMode |
CFRunLoopRunSpecific | __CFRunLoopRun
| __CFRunLoopDoTimer |
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
| __NSFireDelayedPerform |
-[todoListViewController drillDocumentMenu:] |
-[documentListViewController drillIntoDocumentWithToDoRecord:] |
-[documentViewController OpenTodoDocument:OfType:WithPath:] |
-[documentViewController OpenDocumentOfType:WithPath:] |
-[documentViewController managePDFDocumentWithPath:] |
-[ScrollViewWithPagingViewController init] | -[UIView init] |
-[UIScrollView initWithFrame:] | -[UIView initWithFrame:] | UIViewCommonInitWithFrame | -[UIView
_createLayerWithFrame:] | +[NSObject(NSObject) alloc] | +[NSObject(NSObject) allocWithZone:] | class_createInstance |
_internal_class_createInstanceFromZone | calloc | malloc_zone_calloc
```

**What i don't understand though is if it the history was ALLOC,FREE,ALLOC then why does the error indicate that it was released (net +1 alloc)?**

**or is my understanding of the dump wrong?**

---

EDIT (fresh run= different object pointers):

Zombie Detection with instruments:

[image]

Why and how, does the retain count jump from 1 to -1?

Looking at the backtrace of the Zombie, looks like the retain count is being called by: Quartz through release_root_if_unused

[image]

---

Edit: **Solved**- I was removing a view from super, then releasing it. Fixed by just releasing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kay is correct;  the malloc history is showing two allocations at the specified address;  one that has been allocated and freed and one that is still in play.

What you need is the backtrace of the call to `retainCount` on the `CALayer` that has already been released.  Because you have zombie detection enabled, amongst other memory debugging things, it may be that the deallocation simply has not & will not happen.

Mixing malloc history with zombie detection changes the runtime behavior significantly.

I'd suggest running with zombie detection in Instruments.   Hopefully, that'll pinpoint the exact problem.

If not, then there is a breakpoint you can set to break when a zombie is messaged.  Set that breakpoint and see where you stop.

---

OK -- so, CoreAnimation is using the retain count for internal purposes (the system frameworks can get away with this, fragile though it is).

I think the -1 is a red herring;  it is likely that zombies return 0xFF....FFFF as the retain count and this is rendered as -1 in Instruments.

Next best guess;  since this is happening in a timer, the over-release is probably happening during animation.   The CoreAnimation layers should handle this correctly.  There is an over-release of a view or animation layer container in your code that is causing the layer to go away prematurely.

Have you tried "Build and Analyze"?  Off-chance it might catch the mismanagement of a view somewhere.

In any case and as an experiment, try retaining your view(s) an extra time and see if that makes this problem stop.  If it does, that is, at least, a clue.

(Or it might be a bug in the system frameworks... maybe... but doubtful.)

Finally, *who the heck is calling `retainCount`?!?!?*  In the case of CoreAnimation, it is possible that the `retainCount` is being used internally as an implementation detail.

If it is your code, though, then the location of the zombie call should be pretty apparent.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, Tracked the issue down: I was removing a view from super that  had a child view and a (grand)child layer, then releasing the view after this. Instead now i just release. It only started happening since i updated the app to 4.2 (ipad)- So Lesson Learned. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but if you take a look at the first line in block 3:

> ALLOC **0x4dbb170**-0x4dbb19f [size=**48**]:

While in the other two outputs a memory block of size 18 at 0x4dbb160-0x4dbb171 was allocated and freed. I assume the old object was freed and there is a new object residing at this memory address. Thus the old instance at 0x...b160 is not valid any longer.

Comment: I thought the size might have been an indicator. An object's id is the start address so the object alloc'd in block 3 is the one causing my problems (Since its start address is the object reported in console).

Comment: What i don't understand is it shows clearly here it's allocated. but the error indicates its been released...

Comment: You are right, I would expect a 4th entry in malloc history indicating a free for b170. Maybe the pointer to the memory itself has been corrupted? Did you enable "Stop on Obj-C exceptions" in Run menu? There is a web site I bookmarked some time ago http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html . Maybe you find some hints over there.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS is not an exception, it is a crash.  Stop on Obj-C exceptions won't stop on it (but the debugger always will).