# View the malloc history in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2, malloc-history

I'm trying to find a deallocated instance error in Xcode 4.2. I've Zombie Objects, Guard Malloc and Malloc Stack options enabled.

In the console I use Shell malloc_history pid adress and shows nothing.

My question is anybody knows how view the malloc history of an object in Xcode 4.2 or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you input the right pid and address.
This reference may help you:

[Understanding a malloc_history dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366226/understanding-a-malloc-history-dump)